# Is there any way to generate Xlsx (2007) using xmlss?

Tags: java, javascript, xml, apache-poi, xlsx

When saving an excel sheet (xls - 2330) in .xml form, the xmlss file will contain the respective xsl code. But in xlsx i can't save the file with .xml format.

Also is there any specific Apache POI API availabe to convert .xls (2003) to .xlsx(2007) format?

Since the POI creates the xmlss file to create the xlsx, is there any simpler option?

related links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_xmlss_x:header

Greetings in advance.

Comment: "conver .xsl to .xlsx format?" XSL is style information, not a spreadsheet. Do you mean xls?

Comment: Yes hexafraction. I ve missed that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089039/how-to-load-old-microsoft-office-xml-file-excel-using-java). At least the JODConverter approach could help you ...